# How to change element value in JS variable

Tags: jquery, variables, dom

How can i change name of input, if is my DOM saved in JS variable?

```
var data = '<input id="layout_name" name="link" type="text" value="">';
```

i need change value of parameter name to link[1] (im using jQuery library in this project)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't save it as a text value. Use DOM elements in JS.

Comment: Here's a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

Comment: `data = $(data).prop('name', 'link[1]').get(0).outerHTML;` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/354q3/**

Comment: ^^ and manipulating HTML string like this is generally a bad idea !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = '<input id="layout_name" name="link" type="text" value="">';
var $input = $(data);
$input.attr('name', 'other');
data = $input[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do just with the 'data' variable ( without using $input) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
var data = $('<input id="layout_name" name="link" type="text" value="">');
data.attr('name', 'new_value');
```

You can create `HTMLElements` directly with jQuery